# How do i calculate the center and radius of an arc drawn by canvas arcTo

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, transform

I draw a circular arc by calling the arcTo() function in canvas. I want to calculate the center coordinate of the arc but I don't know how to calculate the radius of the arc after applying a transform in canvas.

Here is my code to calculate the radius:

```
    function getActualRadius(ctx, radius) {
      const transform = ctx.getTransform();
      const sx = Math.sqrt(transform.a * transform.a + transform.c * transform.c);
      const sy = Math.sqrt(transform.b * transform.b + transform.d * transform.d);
      const theta = Math.atan2(transform.b, transform.a);
      return Math.abs(sx * sy) * radius / Math.abs(Math.cos(theta));
    }
```

Comment: The way I read the docs, the transformation in effect might not be orthogonal, so the arc in the current coordinate system might actually turn out to be an ellipse in device pixel coordinates. Do you want to restrict your question to only orthogonal transformations?

Comment: I think i should restrict the question to only orthogonal transformations. So if there is a method i can calculate the start and end coordinate of the arc@MvG